# How To Make Post Using Pagination in Blogger?

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, blogger

I have created pagination from 1 to 10 post. But, when I click on 1 or 2 page. It is not getting change like visited page or active page. Hence, help me to do it...

**Below is the css code:**

```
.post-pagination {
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
}
.button_1, .button_2, .button_3, .button_4, .button_5, .button_6, .button_7, .button_8, .button_9, .button_10 {
    border: 2px solid #f4655f;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    color:#f4655f;
    transition:ease 0.69s !important;
}
.button_1:hover, .button_2:hover, .button_3:hover, .button_4:hover, .button_5:hover, .button_6:hover, .button_7:hover, .button_8:hover, .button_9:hover, .button_10:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f4655f;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.post-pagination a {
    color:#4876ff;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left: 7%;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0.5px;
}
```

**Here is the jQuery code:**

```
<script style='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(&#39;.button_1&#39;).click(function(){
jQuery(&#39;.content_1&#39;).show();
jQuery(&#39;.content_2&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_3&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_4&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_5&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_6&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_7&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_8&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_9&#39;).hide();
jQuery(&#39;.content_10&#39;).hide();
return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved using below coding. I thought to update my answer. So, that other users can get benifit from it :)

```
Below - <head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


Above: 
    ]]></b:skin>

<!-- Pagination Script -->
.post-pagination {
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.post-pagination a {
    color:#f4655f;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    left: 7%;
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0.5px;
}
.button_1, .button_2, .button_3, .button_4, .button_5, .button_6, .button_7, .button_8, .button_9, .button_10 {
    border: 2px solid #f4655f;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    color:#f4655f;
    transition:ease 0.69s !important;
}
.button_1:hover, .button_2:hover, .button_3:hover, .button_4:hover, .button_5:hover, .button_6:hover, .button_7:hover, .button_8:hover, .button_9:hover, .button_10:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f4655f;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
<!-- Pagination Script End Here -->


Above: </head  

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.button_1').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_2').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_3').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_4').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_5').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_6').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_7').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_8').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_9').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_10').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_10').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
jQuery('.button_10').click(function(){
jQuery('.content_1').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_2').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_3').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_4').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_5').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_6').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_7').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_8').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_9').fadeOut('fast');
jQuery('.content_10').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery(this).css('background','#F4655F');
jQuery(this).css('color','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_1').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_2').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_2').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_3').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_3').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_4').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_4').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_5').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_5').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_6').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_6').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_7').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_7').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_8').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_8').css('color','#F4655F');
jQuery('.button_9').css('background','#fff');
jQuery('.button_9').css('color','#F4655F');
return false;
});
});
</script>
```